# Проблема авторизации vk api (не авторизирует сообщество)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пишу бота, авторизирую сообщество через:

```
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="dfc656aa23f41e33.....0a59dfdfc74c5f7b9")
vk.auth()
```

В ответ вижу вот это:

```
File "C:\Users\evgeny_lucky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 143, in auth
raise LoginRequired('Login is required to auth')
vk_api.exceptions.LoginRequired: Login is required to auth
```

Одна знакомая сказала что это как-то связано с версиями API и питона, может кто-то знает причину почему авторизация не проходит?

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте vk.auth() при авторизации через токен.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]